# Resources for test automation

Tags: automated-testing

I'm trying to learn more about test automation as it relates to the QA process and there just doesn't seem to be a lot of resources out there.  For example, if I do a search for TestComplete (a tool I'm now evaluating), the first few pages of Google results are all links from the company's website instead of external websites referencing the tool or providing tutorials/tips/tricks, etc.  If I search for QTP even the company's own website for the tool appears elusive and there just isn't much online for it.

Another thing I'm looking into is customized automation tools, ones that can I build myself in .NET.  Again, there's not a lot out there - hardly any books or websites.

Is the demand for test automation that low?  I would think with all the software in the world that test automation would be something that would be highly sought after or would at least be rapidly growing.

EDIT: Sorry for the delay, but basically I'm looking for two things:

1) External websites (those outside the company's website) that discuss or provide tutorials on various tools, like things you would find with standard development tools, or even books that cover these tools.
2) Creating your own automated tools vs using existing tools - why go one route vs another?  Regarding the SQAForum website, it seems like all discussions focus on existing tools, but what about people discussing the creation of their own testing tools?

I was searching for the Microsoft Automation UI framework specifically and only came up with a couple examples.  The book ".NET Test Recipes" is a bit old and there are some newer frameworks out there that wouldn't  be covered.

It seems like most of the big companies that use SDETs rely on their own tools they create instead of out of the box tools, but discussion on creating these tools, tutorials, etc are more limited.

Comment: Hi, Ryan, I'm not quite sure what it is you're asking here - are you asking why there seems to be a dearth of resources and information about test automation, or are you wanting more information about the various tools?

Comment: I'm not sure how you reached the conclusion that demand for test automation is low. My experience is exactly the opposite. Perhaps you need to try different Google searches, looking beyond the first few results.

Comment: There are a myriad of test automation frameworks.  Are you looking specifically for user interface automation?  And if so, are you interested in testing native applications or browser-based applications?

Answer (score 7):

There's a huge amount of material out there - what search terms have you been using ?
A quick search through testing blogs will soon find arguments about whether testers should know coding or not as there is so much demand for SDETs ( Sofware Developers in Test ) and plenty of discussion about Automation v Automagic ( TM Jim Hazen )

Sadly, if you search on the tool names then yeh, you're going to find the marketing bumf from the tool vendors

What exactly are you looking for - info on tools or info on the approach you should take for automation ? What are you trying to automate - desktop apps, browser based apps, mobile, SAP ?

For .NET there are a couple of books out there eg
[.NET Test Automation Recipes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590596633)

EDIT

Now you've provided more info

Might be worth reading [this article](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-10/lightsabers-time-machines--other-automation-heuristics) about automation and frameworks by Adam Goucher

Comment: I want to look at existing packages to see if there is something out there that can do what I need.  I've been looking at TestComplete and haven't been too pleased with some things, but the only place where there seems to be much discussion is on the SmartBear forums (company who makes the tool).  QTP is another tool we're looking at, although I haven't evaluated it yet.  There just isn't a whole lot out there in the way of user champions comparing these tools or tutorials on how to get the most out of them like you find with "regular" software devs.

Comment: Could you expand more on what 'your need' is ? ( if you can expand, then add it to your original post ? )

Comment: Keep looking Ryan. Go to SQAForums.com and see hundreds of thousands of members discussing many, many tools and frameworks.

Comment: @Phil: I've updated my original question.

Comment: @Ryan - added a link to a useful ( I hope ) article about frameworks and automation

Answer (score 2):

Almost any major framework or tool is customizable, meaning that:

- you can code your own verifications and pass/fail logic
- you can run external tools
- you can customize logs and push/pull of test results in some way

[Rational Functional tester](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/functional/) uses Java language, [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/) uses C# (if you wish to use .NET), and Sikuli uses Python (but it isn't mature enough).

Where I work, software testing has recently grown in importance, but simply our managers can't fully understand how it works (unit tests, integration tests, functional tests...) and what can be automated and what can not.
Also *automated testing* is often misunterstood and interpreted as *testing done by the machine so having immediate results*.

This is mainly my experience, I hope it answers a part of your question.

Comment: Spam filters prevented me from posting http://sikuli.org hyperlink, so here it is.